# Set cookie before redirecting doesn't work

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie before redirecting to the site.
This is what I did:

On a.com I've put on he main page the code:

```
<img src="https://www.b.com/cookie.php " style="display:none;" />
```

The Cookie.php from b.com has the following code:

```
<?
setcookie("age_gate", "1", time()+3600, “/”,”www.b.com”,  false);
?>
```

On the Mainpage is a button that redirects you to the b.com Website. When I click on the button to get redirected the cookie doesn't get set.

If I access the link https://www.b.com/cookie.php the cookie gets set.

Comment: Do you see `set-cookie` at `headers` in `network` in _devTools_? Is there any warning (small exclamation mark next to the header name)?

Comment: Does the browser even request the script, when you hide the image using `display:none`?

Comment: This might also simply be your browser blocking the cookie as a 3rd-party cookie. (Which is a default these days in many more privacy focused browsers, so this isn't a "solution" you should expect to work reliably in the wild to begin with.)

Comment: @CBroe do you have a solution for that? this cookie should be a bypass for the age verification pop-up when you get redirected from the page as you already have to go through the age verification process on the a.com website.

Comment: @Jax-p no I don't see it

Comment: If you don't even see the Set-Cookie header for that request, then you don't need to look for a solution to a potential 3rd-party issue yet. Does the browser even make the request? (And if not, does that change when you remove `display: none` from the image?

Comment: But about the 3rd-party cookie issue you can't do much, in general - because if _you_ could, then any data hungry tracking company that wants to invade my privacy by tracking me across any number of different domains, could do as well. So for the privacy protection aspect to work, there _must not_ be any "workarounds."

Comment: Alright, thought i could use 3rd party cookies for that. I just found a function that's integrated into the plugin that does the trick.

Thanks for the help.